# What are the advantages of using Jack and Jill?

Tags: android, android-jack-and-jill

After announcement of Android N, Google officially launching Jack toolchain with Android Studios 2.1.

The main advantages of Jack (due to this [page](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html)) are:

> **Completely open source**
>
> Available in AOSP; partners are welcome to contribute.
>
> **Speeds compilation time**
>
> Jack has specific supports to reduce compilation time: pre-dexing,
> incremental compilation and a Jack compilation server.
>
> **Handles shrinking, obfuscation, repackaging and multidex**
>
> Using a separate package such as ProGuard is no longer necessary.

But annotation processing, code weaving (e.g. aspectj) , bytecode manipulation are not supported (which are really important for me).

Also speeds compilation time was not sensible for me, I created a sample project with a little bunch of dependencies and in both jack and default compiler, the compile and build time was less than 10-15 seconds.

So Why do I migrate to Jack?

Comment: Why do you say that bytecode manipulation is not supported?  There is a new Transform API that lets you do this.  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api

Comment: @saeed what do you mean compile time was less than 10-15 seconds? Jack is slower?

Comment: You are happy guy, compile my project with current compiler takes 3 minutes and 50s on my project :-) But personally I don't understand why is not possible to do class -> dex compilation faster, but jack ->dex yes. Probably the structure of jack is specially optimized to make the conversion easier.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm using javassist and i can not use that Transform API

Comment: Since Google uses annotation processing all over the place, I am reasonably certain that Jack supports it.

Comment: @Haded compiling, building and then running my project takes less than 10 or 20 seconds for both compilers, So i can't see any "reduce compilation time" in Jack

Comment: @DougStevenson The document says`Jack does not use this API at the moment.`

Comment: @Saeed It should eventually.  Jack and Jill are not ready for general use yet, but when they are, they should be a transparent replacement for the current compiler and dexer, assuming that there are no strange tricks being played with internal tasks created by the android gradle plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now with Android Gradle Plugin version 2.2.0-alpha1 or higher, annotation processing is supported by default.

Also due to this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210730) transform API, which is useful for bytecode weaving, will be supported later.